# Reading float type numbers from a .txt file and using them in formulas

Tags: c++, floating-point, fstream

I am trying to read numbers from a .txt file and use them in formulas within my code and output the results into another .txt file so I can use them easier. My problem is reading the 3000 lines of numbers and assigning them the variable to use in the formulas. The first column I need to the variable dt and the second column I would like it to be the variable i. For whatever reason, I can't get them to read correctly. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void GetAcc(const float Acc[], const float Vel[], float Pos[], float dt);
void GetVel(const float Acc[], float Vel[], float dt);

int main()

{
    float Position[3000]={0};
    float Velocity[3000]={0};
    float Acceleration[3000]={0};
    float i;
    float dt;

    FILE *fp;

    fp=fopen("M3 Array File.txt", "r+");
     fscanf(fp,"%f",&dt);
     fscanf(fp,"%f",&i);


    GetVel(Acceleration,Velocity,dt);
    GetAcc(Acceleration,Velocity,Position,dt);

    for(i=0;i<3000;i++)  fprintf(fp,"%3.3f\t%3.3f\t%3.3f\t%3.3f\n",dt*(float)i,Acceleration[i],Velocity[i],Position[i]);
    fclose(fp);

    return  0;
}

void GetVel(const float Acc[], float Vel[], float dt)
{
    int i;

    for(i=1;i<3000;i++)
    {
        Vel[i]=Vel[i-1]+Acc[i]*dt;
    }
}

void GetAcc(const float Acc[], const float Vel[], float Pos[], float dt)
{
    int i;

    for(i=1;i<3000;i++)
    {
        Acc[i]=2*Pos[i]-Pos[i-1]-Vel[i-1];
    }
}
```

Here is an example of what the file looks like.

```
0.000   0.000
0.001   0.000
0.002   0.000
0.003   0.000
0.004   0.000
0.005   0.000
0.006   0.000
0.007   0.000
0.008   0.000
0.009   0.000
0.010   0.000
0.011   0.000
0.012   0.000
0.013   0.000
0.014   0.000
0.015   0.000
0.016   0.000
0.017   0.000
0.018   0.000
0.019   0.000
0.020   0.000
0.021   0.000
0.022   0.000
0.023   0.000
0.024   0.000
0.025   0.000
0.026   0.000
0.027   0.000
0.028   0.000
0.029   0.000
0.030   0.002
0.031   0.003
0.032   0.005
0.033   0.005
0.034   0.005
0.035   0.005
0.036   0.005
0.037   0.006
0.038   0.008
0.039   0.009
0.040   0.011
0.041   0.012
0.042   0.012
0.043   0.012
0.044   0.012
0.045   0.014
0.046   0.015
0.047   0.017
0.048   0.018
0.049   0.020
0.050   0.021
0.051   0.023
0.052   0.025
0.053   0.026
0.054   0.028
0.055   0.029
0.056   0.031
0.057   0.032
0.058   0.034
0.059   0.035
0.060   0.037
0.061   0.040
0.062   0.043
0.063   0.046
0.064   0.049
0.065   0.052
0.066   0.054
0.067   0.055
0.068   0.057
0.069   0.060
0.070   0.063
0.071   0.066
0.072   0.069
0.073   0.072
0.074   0.075
0.075   0.078
0.076   0.081
0.077   0.084
0.078   0.087
0.079   0.091
0.080   0.095
0.081   0.100
0.082   0.104
0.083   0.109
0.084   0.114
0.085   0.117
0.086   0.120
0.087   0.123
0.088   0.127
0.089   0.132
0.090   0.137
0.091   0.141
0.092   0.146
0.093   0.150
0.094   0.155
0.095   0.161
0.096   0.167
0.097   0.173
0.098   0.179
0.099   0.184
0.100   0.189
0.101   0.193
0.102   0.199
0.103   0.206
0.104   0.212
0.105   0.218
0.106   0.224
0.107   0.230
0.108   0.236
0.109   0.242
0.110   0.250
0.111   0.258
0.112   0.265
0.113   0.273
0.114   0.281
0.115   0.288
0.116   0.296
0.117   0.304
0.118   0.311
0.119   0.319
0.120   0.327
0.121   0.334
0.122   0.342
0.123   0.350
0.124   0.359
0.125   0.368
0.126   0.377
0.127   0.387
0.128   0.396
0.129   0.405
0.130   0.414
0.131   0.423
0.132   0.433
0.133   0.442
0.134   0.451
0.135   0.460
0.136   0.471
0.137   0.482
0.138   0.492
0.139   0.503
0.140   0.514
0.141   0.525
0.142   0.535
0.143   0.546
0.144   0.557
0.145   0.569
0.146   0.581
0.147   0.594
0.148   0.606
0.149   0.618
0.150   0.630
0.151   0.643
0.152   0.655
0.153   0.667
0.154   0.680
0.155   0.692
0.156   0.706
0.157   0.719
0.158   0.733
0.159   0.747
0.160   0.761
0.161   0.775
0.162   0.788
0.163   0.802
0.164   0.816
0.165   0.830
0.166   0.845
0.167   0.861
0.168   0.876
0.169   0.891
0.170   0.907
0.171   0.922
0.172   0.937
0.173   0.953
0.174   0.969
0.175   0.986
0.176   1.003
0.177   1.020
0.178   1.037
0.179   1.054
0.180   1.071
0.181   1.088
0.182   1.104
0.183   1.121
0.184   1.140
0.185   1.158
0.186   1.177
0.187   1.195
0.188   1.213
0.189   1.232
0.190   1.250
0.191   1.269
0.192   1.287
0.193   1.307
0.194   1.327
0.195   1.347
0.196   1.367
0.197   1.387
0.198   1.407
0.199   1.427
0.200   1.447
0.201   1.468
0.202   1.489
0.203   1.511
0.204   1.532
0.205   1.554
0.206   1.575
0.207   1.597
0.208   1.618
0.209   1.640
0.210   1.663
0.211   1.686
0.212   1.709
0.213   1.732
0.214   1.755
0.215   1.778
0.216   1.801
0.217   1.824
0.218   1.848
0.219   1.873
0.220   1.898
0.221   1.922
0.222   1.947
0.223   1.971
0.224   1.996
0.225   2.020
0.226   2.045
0.227   2.071
0.228   2.097
0.229   2.123
0.230   2.149
0.231   2.175
0.232   2.201
0.233   2.227
0.234   2.255
0.235   2.283
0.236   2.310
0.237   2.338
0.238   2.365
0.239   2.393
0.240   2.421
0.241   2.448
0.242   2.476
0.243   2.505
0.244   2.534
0.245   2.563
0.246   2.592
0.247   2.622
0.248   2.651
0.249   2.680
0.250   2.709
0.251   2.740
0.252   2.770
0.253   2.801
0.254   2.832
0.255   2.862
0.256   2.893
0.257   2.924
0.258   2.954
0.259   2.987
0.260   3.019
0.261   3.051
0.262   3.083
0.263   3.116
0.264   3.148
0.265   3.180
0.266   3.212
0.267   3.246
0.268   3.280
0.269   3.313
0.270   3.347
0.271   3.381
0.272   3.415
0.273   3.448
0.274   3.482
0.275   3.517
0.276   3.553
0.277   3.588
0.278   3.623
0.279   3.659
0.280   3.694
0.281   3.729
0.282   3.764
0.283   3.800
0.284   3.836
0.285   3.873
0.286   3.910
0.287   3.947
0.288   3.984
0.289   4.021
0.290   4.057
0.291   4.094
0.292   4.133
0.293   4.171
0.294   4.209
0.295   4.248
0.296   4.286
0.297   4.324
0.298   4.363
0.299   4.401
0.300   4.439
0.301   4.479
0.302   4.519
0.303   4.559
0.304   4.599
0.305   4.639
0.306   4.679
0.307   4.719
0.308   4.758
0.309   4.800
0.310   4.841
0.311   4.883
0.312   4.924
0.313   4.965
0.314   5.007
0.315   5.048
0.316   5.090
0.317   5.131
0.318   5.174
0.319   5.217
0.320   5.260
0.321   5.303
0.322   5.346
0.323   5.389
0.324   5.432
0.325   5.475
0.326   5.518
0.327   5.562
0.328   5.607
0.329   5.651
0.330   5.696
0.331   5.740
0.332   5.785
0.333   5.829
0.334   5.874
0.335   5.918
0.336   5.963
0.337   6.009
0.338   6.055
0.339   6.101
0.340   6.147
0.341   6.193
0.342   6.239
0.343   6.285
0.344   6.331
0.345   6.378
0.346   6.426
0.347   6.473
```

Comment: Do you know how to use fscanf? Also, these are not integers. Integers are whole numbers: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4... and negative ones -1, -2, -3...

Comment: converting string to double is expensive, esp. when there are a lot of them like this case. It's better to read/write the file in binary

Answer (score 0):

You can use tokenize in c++

Spliting string into two with blank space

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
string line;

istringstream buf(line);
istream_iterator<string> beg(buf), end;
vector<string> tokens(beg, end);
cout << "1st sub String : " << tokens[0];
cout << "2nd sub String : " << tokens[1];
```

Casting string to an int

```
int n;
stringstream num(tokens[1]);
num >> n;
```

These snippets might help you, Ref :

https://binaramedawatta.blogspot.com/2018/12/supporting-code-snippets-for-oop-take.html

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/converting-strings-numbers-cc/

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/87238/